# how to divide my datasets into subfolder in sequences like 001-002 -003?

Tags: python

I use this code to my datasets but images don't copy in sequences in subfolder.
the order is necessary i.e copying images in a sequential manner and not in any random order

```
## divided

import os
import shutil
output_location = "location where you want to save them" 
# better not to be in the same location with the dataset
dataset_path = "your data set"
files = [os.path.join(path, file) for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(dataset_path) for file in files]

nr_of_files = 0
folder_name = ""
for index in range(len(files)):
    if nr_of_files == 0:
        folder_name = os.path.join(output_location, files[index].split("\\")[-1].split(".")[0])
        os.mkdir(folder_name)
        shutil.copy(files[index], files[index].replace(dataset_path, folder_name))
        nr_of_files += 1
    elif nr_of_files == 11:
        shutil.copy(files[index], files[index].replace(dataset_path, folder_name))
        nr_of_files = 0
    else:
        shutil.copy(files[index], files[index].replace(dataset_path, folder_name))
        nr_of_files += 1
```